# Hacer una validación de que un usuario ya existe en la base de datos sql server

Tags: angular, api, .net, entity-framework

Necesito que al momento de crear un nuevo usuario al apretar el botón aceptar y recoger el dato input(correo) que me diga si ese correo esta en uso y registrado en la base de datos, estoy haciendo la aplicación con angular 11 .net entity framework consumiéndolo en una api.

Me serviría una idea de cómo hacerlo aunque si tenéis código por ahí mejor. Saludos

```
onSubmit(){
    this.gestionClienteService.cliente = this.gestionClienteService.formularioRegistroCliente.value;

    if(this.gestionClienteService.cliente.IdCliente == 0 || this.gestionClienteService.cliente.IdCliente == null)
      this.guardarEmpleado();
    else
      this.editarEmpleado();
  }

  guardarEmpleado(){
    this.gestionClienteService.guardarCliente().subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.gestionClienteService.formularioRegistroCliente.reset();
        this.toastr.success("Registro exitoso", "Registro Ciente")
      },
      err=>{
        this.toastr.error("Error")
      }
    );
  }
```

```
// POST: api/Clientes
        // To protect from overposting attacks, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Cliente>> PostCliente(Cliente cliente)
        {
            _context.Clientes.Add(cliente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetCliente", new { id = cliente.IdCliente }, cliente);
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido, te recomiendo que leas [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  y adaptes tu pregunta para que sea fácilmente entendible. 

El colocar imágenes en lugar del código no favorece mucho la comprensión de la pregunta. Lo idóneo sería que sustituyeses las imágenes por tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Si la API esta bien hecha, debería de devolver [estados de respuesta HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) y Mensajes, lo que te serviría para controlarlo desde el Front. Por ejemplo, si el usuario no existe debería devolver un 404. Con esto podrías validar si es un 200 (o un 202) significa que existe y si es un 404 que no existe dicho usuario.

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]